# Create colorcoded ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

My vision is to create a color coded listView, where I want to have a slim colored bar in each item's layout. This bar should be a certain color based on an int I pass to the activity. How do I create such a bar(essentially a filled rectangle) and set its color. Currently, I am using a custom layout for my list and using a SimpleAdapter with an ArrayList.

I know I will have to use

```
if (integerForColor == someNumber)
    //set the color of the shape, bar
```

I am sure this is a simple thing that I simply cannot think of at the moment, or must be missing a fundamental. Thank you in advance for your effort.

**EDIT 1**:

Trying to decode some of the answers that were here, I realized that you guys need my code on how I am building my list:

```
public class AddScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listthings;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
from = new String[] { "row_1", "row_2" };
to = new int[] { R.id.row1, R.id.row2 };

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout,
            from, to);

listthings.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

**I have added the getView() Method**:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.red);
    return convertView;
      //I have no inflater as of now...
}
```

[image]
**EDIT 2**: As per @huntsfromshadow 's suggestion, I have created a new activity and overridden the getView() method there.

```
//Imports
 public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter{

public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    row.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
    return row;

}

}
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom adapter and override getView.  That is the point where you can do any complicated layout decisions based on values and logic.

A google search for custom adapter will give you a lot of resources.

Comment: I am still not sure on how to do this. could you please provide some sample code for this scenario?

Comment: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  is a good example of how to create a custom array adapter.  The basics are the same for array, cursor, etc.  They all work by overriding methods of the adapter you need (typically getView)

Comment: You need to add the overrided getView to a subclass of of an adapter, not to the activity.  So extend SimpleAdapater and do an override of get view in their.

Comment: does that mean i need to create another .java file? For the adapter, I am simply using mylayout.xml( just a layout file)....

Comment: Well you aren't creating a view on getView.  ConvertView is either null or an existing view.  Please take a look at the links everyone posted and the actual javadocs for android. It explains in great detail what these methods do and where they come from.  It is far better if you understand what is happening then people on stack overflow just giving you answers.  This is a very common pattern for listviews and you'll be doing it a lot.

Comment: thanks huntsfromshadow. I have gotten this working by reading some info on this. turns out i needed to inflate it, etc. Unfortunately I am having problem because when i create a custom SimpleAdapter, the text View is not updating the text I need it to. This was working perfectly before. Can you help me on this? With what i was using earlier, I never even needed to initialize the TextViews. why is this? link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916584/custom-simpleadapter-only-shows-sample-text-android/6916722#6916722

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have everything else setup,
it's probably easiest to define your colored backgrounds in xml like so (red.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#DD0000"
        android:endColor="#EE0000"
        android:angle="270" />
 </shape>
```

And then use it like this:

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.red).
```

You'll have to pass in and save a context object from the parent `Activity`.

Look at the answer I gave on how to create a ListView (yes it's parsing data from JSON - ignore that) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364698/parsing-json-to-listview/6364885#6364885)

Comment: thank you for that. So how do I set a certain listView Item's rectangle/bar/shape to a red color?

Comment: Check out the link I provided - it provides full instructions.

Comment: i am still slightly confused. Can you check out the code I updated... I hope it will help in how I am creating the list and show you how you can help...

Comment: Ok, the key thing is to extend SimpleAdapter, not array adapter, as the example in the link shows. Make yourself a class holding a reference to the integer id of the color (R.drawable.item) and store it in the Adapter. The example shows how do that.

Comment: im sorry for not keeping you updated, but I have solved this problem. I am encountering a different, but related thing here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916584/custom-simpleadapter-only-shows-sample-text-android/6916722#6916722. Please take a look at the comment I added to the one answer that is there. That is why it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

As @CaspNZ said, use .xml shape files.

In your code extend a 'ListAdapter' (probably either BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter).  Override the getView function like this:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if (convertView == null){
        //assuming you already have inflater initilized somewhere
        convertView = inflater.inflate(you_layout_file.xml, parent, false);
    }

    //some logic to determine what color the background should be
    convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.the_file_you_want_to_use.xml)
}
```

Comment: something is still not working. Although i have not yet added the logic, can you please look at my updated code and see how you can help?

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together something very similar to color code the text of each item differently.  You could adapt it pretty easily to change the color of a bar instead.

Since each element in the list has a different color, you have to remember which color is associated with which location in the array.  I just used a simple integer array as a member of my ColorItemsAdapter.

```
private class ColorItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    /*
     * For each line to be added to the log, the text is stored in "items"
     * and the text color is stored in "colors"
     */
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int length = 0;

    public ColorItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> stringObj)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stringObj);
        if(stringObj != null)
        {
            length = stringObj.size();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the adapter, and specifies what color the item should be
     * @param item
     * The text to be added
     * @param color
     * The color of the text to be added
     */
    public void add(String item, Integer color)
    {
        items.add(item);
        colors.add(color);
        length++;
        super.add(item);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the adapter at position <i>index</i>
     * @param item
     * The text to be inserted
     * @param index
     * The index at which to insert the text
     * @param color
     * The color of the text to be inserted
     */
    public void insert(String item, int index, Integer color)
    {
        items.add(index, item);
        colors.add(index, color);
        length++;
        super.insert(item, index);
    }

    /*
     * Changes the color of the TextView appropriately before calling the super
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView v = (TextView) convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = (TextView) vi.inflate(R.layout.log_list_item, null);
        }

        /*
         * Here I am setting the text color
         * but you could set some other attribute instead.
         */
        v.setTextColor(colors.get(position));

        return super.getView(position, v, parent);
    }
}
```

Then, to add an item to your list (in this case a red one), you could just use

```
myColorItemsAdapter.insert(message, 0, Color.RED);
```