# Custom SimpleAdapter only shows Sample Text Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, simpleadapter

Before making my own SimpleAdapter object because I wanted to change the color of the rows, I was just using new SimpleAdapter(...). Now that I am using my own custom SimpleAdapter, the row color is changing, but my text is not getting updated. I have called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but it is still showing only the sample text- "TextView". As I said, everything was working fine when I didn't create my own adapter. I suspect it might have something to do with the order I am initializing things:

```
public class AddScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView listthings;
int[] to;
    String[] from;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
listthings = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listthings);
    from = new String[] { "row_1", "row_2" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.row1, R.id.row2 };

    adapter = new Adapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout,
            from, to);

    listthings.setAdapter(adapter);
...
}

public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistlayout, parent, false);
            }
        row.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
       TextView rw1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.row1);
      // TextView rw2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.row2);
       rw1.setText(map.get(position));
       return row;
    }

}
// to add the item, put it in the map, and add the map into the list
private void addItem() {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("row_1", row1);
    map.put("row_2", row2);
    map.put("row_3", painLevelString);
    map.put("row_4", painLocation);
    map.put("row_5", timeOfPainString);
    map.put("row_6",textTreatmentString);
    painItems.add(map);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




}
```

**EDIT:Added Code**

This is how I am getting the data from the intent(onActivityResult()), placed before the addItem Code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        row1 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row1");
        row2 = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.row2");

        painLevelString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painLevel");
        painLocation = data.getStringExtra("painLocation");
        timeOfPainString = data.getStringExtra("com.painLogger.painTime");
        textTreatmentString = data
                .getStringExtra("com.painLogger.treatment");
        addItem();
    }
}
```

*Also, just in case this is relevant the order of placement is this: onCreate() -> custom Adapter class -> onActivityResult() -> addItem()* **

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like. The two TextView fields in each item should be filled with info(which they were, until I did this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it worked previously with just using `new SimpleAdapter(...)` then in your `getView(...)` implementation change the first line to this:

```
View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

And see if that is what you're expecting. Take out the `LayoutInflater` stuff too.

Answer (score 1):

In `getView()`, about where you are setting the row background, you should also set the text for the `TextView`.

Calling  `notifyDataSetChanged()`, doesn't automagically set your texts right, it just causes the `ListView` to redraw the visible rows with the new data...practically calling `getView()` for each row that needs a refresh.

I also suggest setting the background color from the `mylistlayout.xml` file, and if the getView() function starts taking on a few `findViewByID`'s, you should also consider using a "view holder" approach like in this sample: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: you can use setText() to change the text to either `" "` to clear it, or whatever else you may want there.

Comment: @Phil: i see, but the problem is that I want that text to be the variables row1 and row2, which I get from an intent. see my addItem() code. If i simply set that text as row1 and row2 variables, I get a nullPointerException, because they have not yet been set. Why is it that I didn't even need to initialize these TextViews when I was using SimpleAdapter generically, but need to do this now?

Comment: If you only need to change the background, you don't need to extend the `SimpleAdapter`, you only need to add `android:background="#FF0000FF"` to the layout in `mylistlayout.xml`.  If you need to do more than that, then it may be necessary to extend an `Adapter` and bind it to your `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the text in `getView()`. Like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    TextView text;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistlayout, parent, false);
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.more_list_text);
    }
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);
    text.setText(map.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Also, and this is VERY important - store you map as a member variable of the `SimpleAdapter`
ie, put this line at the top of your object definition:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: I have done this, but I am still encountering a NullPointer. Also, what does (map.get(position)) return? Since each item has two textViews, should I do `painItems.get(position).get("row_1")` instead?

Comment: In fact, I think it would be A LOT easier for you to help me if you just looked at this(my whole activity) http://pastebin.com/QiqmJZLd