# how to set text in Bold Before " | "

Tags: java, android

This is my code :

```
for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID)); 
    String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME).replace("|","|\n").replace("|","");
    map.put(KEY_NAME, Heading);
}
```

Output:

> 30 | Section 120 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 – Jurisdiction of

After Parsing I am getting this data, I want to print the string Before `|` in BOLD letter, in this case I want to print `30` in BOLD letter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to use webview for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);
int a=Heading.indexOf("|");
String beforeSubString=Heading.substring(0, a);
String afterSubString=Heading.substring(a, Heading.length()-1);
String final="<b>"+beforeSubString+"<b>"+"|"+afterSubString;
title.setText(Html.fromHtml(final));
```

Comment: title is textview variable where to set final string

Comment: But i have to map it  map.put(KEY_NAME, Heading); then i have print it on listview SimpleAdapter sAdap;
  sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(circularlistparsing.this, menuItems,
    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME },
    new int[] { R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName });
  lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

Comment: custom adapter using simple adapter & hashmap read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916584/custom-simpleadapter-only-shows-sample-text-android

Comment: also try this http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/

Answer (score 1):

Try Html.fromHtml for make some text bold.

```
title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>30</b> | Section 120 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 – Jurisdiction of"));
```

Comment: but i will separate data before | so that i can create HTML of That data please post complete code

Comment: i think you have to use split function . Split function split sting using some character and make string array .

Comment: String text = "30 | Section 120 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 – Jurisdiction of";
  String[] array = text.split("|");
  username.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + array[0] + " </b> " + array[1]));