# Java, dom4j: how to add inline element (b, i, u) in the middle of text

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I have thought this matter enough. I should be able to do this kind of XML:

```
    <root>
     <text>I am <b>text</b>, alright?</text>
    </root>
```

My question is simple: how an earth Im able to do that inline-element (b, i, u) in the middle of text by using dom4j or should I use an alternative way, when making this kind of inline elements?

It is obvious for me, that this won't work:

```
    Element e = rootelem.addElement("text");
    e.addElement("b").setText("text");
```

Anyone? Please tell me how... This drives me insane. :D

Comment: In element this is easiest way to do. [Set Text in Bold][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833007/how-to-set-text-in-bold-before

Comment: Yes that is one option. But for some reason tag characters are written in entities &lt; and &gt;. I use dom4j for writing tried this with Outputstream and FileWriter without success. Therefore I am looking for a "dom4j-way" to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Just don't use `setText`.

There is a difference between "setting the *text value* of a node" (which eradicates all other content the node would have) and "adding a *text node* to a node" (which allows intermixing text nodes with other node types).

Use `addText` for the latter.

```
Element text = rootelem.addElement("text");

text.addText("I am ");
text.addElement("b").addText("text");
text.addText(", alright?");
```

Interface `Element`, method `addText`: [Adds a new Text node with the given text to this element.](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#addText%28java.lang.String%29)

---

As an aside, naming an element `<text>` when in fact it does not contain text at all (but markup) is a bit unfortunate. Maybe something like `<html>` would be a wiser choice.

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my monday! :) And I don't really use that kind of XML. I'm writing dita, but I had to make simple example, because I did not want to use actual XML. But, thanks! Your solution is perfect and now I'm celebrating! :D